# increasing the hadoop task JVM size

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to set the task JVM size (Map task and Reduce task) , it can be done using the the property mapred.child.java.opts . But my concern is ,where do i need to set it . Can i set it using -D option while submitting job or I need to set this propery in each node's mapred-site.xml .

Thanks,
Priyaranjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
-Dmapred.child.java.opts='-Xmx1024m'
```

on the command line to set the tasks memory to 1024 mib.

Similarly in Java code of the job, you can set it as a configuration parameter:

```
conf.set("mapred.child.java.opts", "-Xmx1024m");
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas !! I have a small query at you , is there any way we can know the properties which are meant to set in individual tasktracker .

Comment: @priyaranjan I would only set the maximum number of mappers/reducers on the tasktrackers.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
hadoop jar your.jar package.MainClass -Dmapred.child.java.opts=blar some more args
```